# How to chop a string containing escape sequences to a given length in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have some strings I want to be limited to n characters, and if exceeding n characters - to end with ' ...'. Pretty common

My problem is with the strings containing escape sequences, though.

I can utilize regular expressions in some way probably, but shouldn't there be a simple and elegant solution?

Comment: can you give an example with a string containing escape chars and the desired output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 0):

Just slice the number of characters you need and add the ellipsis … :)

```js
const longstr = 'long string is here'

const shorten = (str, limit, end = '…') => str.slice(0, limit) + end

console.log(shorten(longstr, 10))
```